# ASP VB.Net Check Boxes in GridView not working getting error BC30311 value of type 'Control' cannot be conveted to CheckBox

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, gridview

I have added a check box to a working gridview as below.

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Reasons" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="container">
            <p style="font-weight:800; font-size: 14px; color: #593196;">Open Dissatisfiers - Select Open Dissatisfiers to Add Resolution(s)</p>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridReasons" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-bordered border-primary table-hover table-sm" 
                AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="InteractionID,KeyID" PageSize="10" Font-Size="Smaller" EnableViewState="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectCheckBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="KeyID" HeaderText="Key ID" SortExpression="KeyID" DataFormatString="{0}" ItemStyle-Width="70"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Type_Desc" HeaderText="Dissatisfier" SortExpression="Dissatisfier Type" ItemStyle-Width="300" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Reason_Desc" HeaderText="Reason" SortExpression="Reason_Desc" ItemStyle-Width="300" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Interaction_Reason_Desc" HeaderText="Dissatisifer Details" SortExpression="Interaction_Reason_Desc" ItemStyle-Width="900"/>
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <div> No Open Dissatisfiers/Reasons</div>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>  
        </div>
        </ContentTemplate>    
    </asp:Panel>
```

It fails when it runs the code to go through the Grid View and take action on any that are checked.

```
    Protected Function GetSelectedRows() As Integer
        Dim intCount As Integer = 0
        Dim intRow As Integer = 0

        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridReasons.Rows
            intRow = intRow + 1
            Dim chk As CheckBox = TryCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("SelectCheckBox"), CheckBox)

            If chk Is Nothing Then
                ' Code if nothing found
            Else
                If chk.Checked Then
                    intCount = intCount + 1
                    'Code if checked
                Else
                    ' Code if not checked
                End If
            End If

        Next

        GetSelectedRows = intCount
    End Function
```

This line is causing the error

Dim chk As CheckBox = TryCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("SelectCheckBox"), CheckBox)

I have tried many variations with the same results.

I have tried it with AutoPostBack to both true and false.  I am using visual studio 2022 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Any templated columns as a general rule don't need, nor use the cells() colleciton.

Hence this should work:

```
        Dim chk As CheckBox =
           FindControl("SelectCheckBox")
```

Depending on your project settings, you may well have to re-introduce your cast to a check box.

Comment: Still gives the same error.  With or without cast.